# Rails ActiveRecord Serialized Data Rspec Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'd like to use rspec to test the validity of a serialized hash, but I'm not really sure how to go about it.  Is there a way to verify that hash has specific keys and values?

foo.rb

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :bar
  serialize :bar

end
```

foo_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Route do
  before { @foo = Foo.new(bar: { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }) }

  subject { @foo }

  it { should #????? }
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure serialization is actually working, you'd want to `create` the record, not just initialize it with `new` (i.e. save it to your database, which will then store it as YAML). Then you could read it back in (using `reload` to make sure it's actually retrieving the serialized database version):

```
it "deserializes the hash" do
  @foo.reload.bar.should eq({a: 1, b:2, c: 3})
end
```

Comment: Thank you; I added a `@foo.save` to my before block and was able to reload the `@foo` instance in my test.  Seems to be working now.